# Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate: error MSB8020:

Tags: visual-studio-2012, msbuild

i have Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate version 11.0.61030.00 update 4.
i try to compile with Daffodil toolset platform v60
[enter link description here](http://screencast.com/t/yegTsjlDfunM)

but how fix this error?

Error   4   error MSB8020: The builds tools for v60 (Platform Toolset = 'v60') cannot be found. To build using the v60 build tools, either click the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then select "Update VC++ Projects...". Install v60 to build using the v60 build tools.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V110\Microsoft.Cpp.Platform.targets.

location files from     Daffodil is:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Platforms\Win32\PlatformToolsets\v60

any help pls
ty.

Comment: Probably just exactly what it says, you installed Daffodil but you never installed Visual Studio version 6.  Indeed very hard to find nowadays, you need an auction site like Ebay.  Premium prices, buyer beware.

Answer (score 0):

Right click the project from the solution explorer, click properties, when it opens expand configuration properties and open the general tab.

Within there, there is a field called 'Platform Toolset' drop down the row next to it and choose the option that should have v60 in the title!

Answer (score 0):

In order to use Daffodil in versions later than VS2010, you need the platform toolset of VS2010 installed AND the toolset you want to use, which is VS6. Have you installed both?

> To use these platform toolsets, you must have the targeted version of Visual Studio installed. Currently supported pl
>   Visual Studio 2012/2013/2015
>   Daffodil works fine in VS 2012 and later versions **as long as VS 2010 is also installed.**

Source: https://daffodil.codeplex.com/